# Updated GetBrowser Function to support Edge browsers and Android Stock Browser

Tags: php, browser

When using the built-in get_browser PHP function, if the user is using their default browser, all that's returned is "Default Browser".

the commonly used function getBrowser() does not detect Microsoft Edge or Stock Android.

How do I get a user's browser if it's their default browser?

Comment: Welcome to this site! Thanks for your bit of wisdom, but this is strictly a Q&A site. Please post a question or an answer next time :) Have a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to get a feel of what a good question looks like.

Comment: Can you reword this to be a question/answer pair please so it can get reopened.

Comment: @Flexo Done, sorry, just couldn't think of a way to post the updated version without reopening old questions, which I don't have rep for.

Comment: Self answered questions is great, it just needs to be in the form of asking and answering a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This getBrowser function can collect the user's browser string in an easy to read way. I've modified it to also recognize Edge and Android.

```
function getBrowser(){
$u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$bname = 'Unknown';
$platform = 'Unknown';
$version= "";

//First get the platform?
if (preg_match('/linux|android/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'linux';
}
elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'mac';
}
elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'windows';
}

// Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
if (preg_match('/android/i', $u_agent)) {
    $bname = 'Android';
    $ub = "Android";
}
elseif(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
    $ub = "MSIE";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Windows NT 10/i',$u_agent) && preg_match('/Edge/i',$u_agent)){
    $bname = 'Microsoft Edge';
    $ub = "Edge";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
    $ub = "Firefox";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Google Chrome';
    $ub = "Chrome";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Apple Safari';
    $ub = "Safari";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Opera';
    $ub = "Opera";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Netscape';
    $ub = "Netscape";
}

// finally get the correct version number
$known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
$pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
    // we have no matching number just continue
}

// see how many we have
$i = count($matches['browser']);
if ($i != 1) {
    //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
    //see if version is before or after the name
    if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][1];
    }
}
else {
    $version= $matches['version'][0];
}

// check if we have a number
if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

return array(
    'userAgent' => $u_agent,
    'name'      => $bname,
    'version'   => $version,
    'platform'  => $platform,
    'pattern'    => $pattern
);
}
// now try it
$browser=getBrowser();
echo "Your browser: " . $browser['name'] . " " . $browser['version'] . " on " .$browser['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $browser['userAgent'];
```